# JS to jQuery conversion

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to convert a JS code into jQuery, can't seem to get it to work after the first if statement.

JS Solution

```
var squares = document.querySelectorAll("td");

function fill() {
    if (this.textContent == '') {
        this.textContent = 'X'
    }else if (this.textContent == 'X') {
        this.textContent = 'O'
    }else{
        this.textContent = ''
    }
}

for (var index = 0; index < squares.length; index++) {
    squares[index].addEventListener('click',fill)
}
```

jQuery attempt

```
$('td').click(fill)

function fill() {
    if ($(this).text("")) {
        $(this).text("X")
    }else if ($(this).text("X")) {
        $(this).text("O")

    }else {
        $(this).text("")
    }
}
```

Comment: by passing an argument to `.text` you are changing the content - not gettingthe value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change to jquery by change `text()` function in `click` event as

```
$('td').click(function(){
  if ($(this).text() == '') {
        $(this).text('X')
    }else if ($(this).text() == 'X') {
        $(this).text('O')
    }else{
        $(this).text('')
    }
})
```

```js
var squares = document.querySelectorAll("td");


$('td').click(function(){
  if ($(this).text() == '') {
        $(this).text('X')
    }else if ($(this).text() == 'X') {
        $(this).text('O')
    }else{
        $(this).text('')
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>



<table>
  <tr>
    <th>A</th>
    <th>B</th>
    <th>C</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>O</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>

 
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! didn't realise you could build the function within it.

Answer (score 0):

In the if condition you are trying to **set value**.

```
$('td').click(fill)

function fill() {
   if ($(this).text()) {
      $(this).text("X")
   }else if ($(this).text() == "X") {
      $(this).text("O")
   }else {
      $(this).text("")
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

TO get text of `td` tag, you can use `.text()`

```
$('td').click(fill);

function fill() {
    if ($(this).text() == "") {
        $(this).text("X")
    }else if ($(this).text() == "X") {
        $(this).text("O")    
    }else {
        $(this).text("")
    }
}
```

You can see my code in this demo: https://codepen.io/phuongnm153/pen/pojXzjE

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want to do this

```js
$('td').click(fill)

function fill() {
  if (!$(this).text()) {
    $(this).text("X")
  } else if ($(this).text() == "X") {
    $(this).text("O")
  } else {
    $(this).text("")
  }
}
```